# "How long do you have" -- what does it mean?

Tags: american-english, north-american-english

"How long do you have?" -- What does that mean?

The conversation regards my potential trip to another country to visit someone.

It means how long I want to stay there? Or How many time I (will) have to stay there?

Comment: 'How long are you going for?' is idiomatic. If you were on a pre-planned coach tour, you could well be asked 'You stay in Switzerland on the tour? How long do you have there?'

Comment: Highly context dependent.  Could mean "How much time until your next train?"  Could mean "How long before you die?"

Comment: ***How long** do you have* = ***How much time** do you have*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This asks how much time you have available. It's usually asked in the context of trying to schedule an activity, to determine how long it could be and fit into your availability. It might be part of an exchange like:

> How long will the meeting be?
>   How long do you have?

The implication is that the meeting will be as long as the person can stay.

I think it's more idiomatic to ask

> How much time do you have?

In the context of a trip you're planning, it might refer to how much time you have free in your schedule.